# Prevent duplicate entries by column

Tags: validation, excel, excel-formula, countif, vba

In Excel, is there a way (non VBA) to have a certain columns not accept entries if they are duplicated elsewhere in that particular column (not all columns, just column B for example)

In the below data, the second entry of EMP_ID 324 would not be allowed

```
Region     EMP_ID   Salary  Yrs_Experience
Chicago     324    $165,140     10
Chicago     234    $162,692     12
NY           56    $122,451     10
NY          567     $98,567     7
SF          344    $116,735     8
SF          324
```

Comment: Excel is not a database ! Database tables have primary keys, Excel does not.

Answer (score 3):

Can be achieved with Data Validation. Assuming `Region` is in A1, select ColumnB, DATA > Data Tools > Data Validation - Data Validation..., Allow: Custom, Formula:

```
  =COUNTIF(B:B,B1)=1
```

OK.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro to administer input. If a duplicate is found, reverse the action and send the user back to the offending cell for a corrected value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then  '<~~something happened in column B
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim dupe As Range
        For Each dupe In Intersect(Target, Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
            If Application.CountIf(Columns(2), dupe.Value2) > 1 Then
                Application.Undo
                dupe.Activate
                Exit For
            End If
        Next dupe
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This should handle a copy and paste into column B so long as the values being pasted in do not create duplicates. I've narrowed the examined cells down to values typed in (aka `xlCellTypeConstants`) but a wider net could also be thrown.